# Select multiple files by file name and get content

Tags: powershell

I run this script for my monitoring system, but i want to extend the range of the aviable date.
Is there any way to get the content of multiple files with different names. Currently im only looking for one specific name pattern, for example, for all files which include a specific date like 2022-08-08*.log.

So what i want to do, is to collect all files from 7 days ago up to 1 day ago at the same time and get the content.

```
$backuppath = "random-name-in-logfile"
$yest = (get-date (get-date).addDays(-1) -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d")
# check for pattern in files
$path1 = Get-ChildItem `
        -Path "C:\path\to\log" -Filter "$yest*.log" -recurse | `
    Select-String -pattern ([regex]::escape($backuppath)) | `
    Select-Object -Property Path
# transform string to usable path
$path2 = $path1 -replace ('@{Path=','') -replace ('}','')
# check for more details
$analyze = Get-Content $path2 | Select-String -pattern "Pattern" -SimpleMatch
```

Comment: So you're only looking for files that have the naming convention of `yyyy-mm-dd`? What's the purpose of searching for a pattern in those files then if your only criteria is met with your first filter? Then, you're searching for another pattern in `$analyze`? Can you clarify, or rephrase what you're asking for? I'm just not understanding what it is you're after by looking at your code.

Comment: I´m checking for the backup state. First I´m looking for the machine (there are multiple machines, but all of them are getting logged into the same directory) by a specific pattern (=backuppath), and after that im looking into this file to check if the backup was finished or failed, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i think i got it.
It´s easier to do by setting the creation time to a limit like 1 day (or for my example 7 days)

```
$path1 = Get-ChildItem `
        -Path "C:\path\to\log" -Filter "*.log" -recurse | `
    Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7) } | `
    Select-String -pattern ([regex]::escape($backuppath)) | `
    Select-Object -Property Path
```